# Conception of a blog/tuto website using spring

Tags: spring, jsp, web-applications, spring-mvc, url-rewriting

I am currently developing a website (with Spring MVC), which I want to use like a blog, with posts about various things. I also want that the post that concern new tutorial that I just published to have a link that redirect to the JSP page which contain this tuto (throw a Spring controller). Moreover, each of those tuto may have some comment.

I created a database which contains the Post objects and Comments objects, linked to these Posts. 
If I want to display the comment about a specific post on the corresponding tuto page, the easiest way is to give an "pageAddress" attribute to the Post object, which will contain the address of the controller method that will redirect to the JSP page of the tuto and give it the comments to display.

The problem is that using this method would force me to use an URL like ".../posts/id_of_the_post", and it is really not good for a tuto address. On the net you always see adress like ".../tutos/name_of_the_tutorial".

The second option would be to use an url like ".../tutos/name_of_the_tutorial", but I would not know the corresponding post and so I would not have the comment associated if the direct address would be ffind throw a search engine.

Do you understand my problem ? I know I didn't explain it very well.

Don't hesitate to propose me any solution. I can change the database or any part of my process.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Make bidirectional OneToOne relationship between Post and Tutorial. Then when you have field "Tutorial" in your post you can make a link this way:

```
<c:set var="postLink" value="/posts/${post.id}" />
<c:if test="${not empty post.tutorial}">
   <c:set var="postLink" value="/tutorials/${post.tutorial.name}" />
</c:if>
<a href="${postLink}">${post.name}</a>
```

If you dont want to have "turorial" field in your "Post" entity you can make unidirectional OneToOne relationship and have only "post" field in your "Tutorial" object. In this case in your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/posts/{postId}")
public Stirng showPost(@PathVariable Long postId) {
   Tutorial tuto = tutorialService.findByPostId(postId);
   if(tuto != null) {
      return "redirect:/tutorials/" + tuto.getName();
   }
   // fetching post object and return show post view
}
```

On "show tutorial" view you can access post comments through ${tutorial.post.comments}

Comment: I see what you mean. Your solution is ok but I didn't plan to have an entity Tutorial, only a JSP page. However it is possible that, in the end, I will have to use one.